# Implementing an Always-Running Redis Client on Android

Tags: java, android, redis, notifications

I'm looking to create a Redis client in my Android app that listens for messages (i.e, notifications) from the server.

This is simple in the foreground. However, it is difficult to keep a service running in the background due to Android's Background Service rules.

The only schedulers in Android that allow a service (i.e, work or job) to rerun periodically are JobSchedular and WorkManager. But both of them have a minimal interval of 15 mins. This is not optimal for an Notification service that needs to be waiting for a notification to arrive and show a notification to the user ASAP.

What is the way to implement a Service that keeps itself running to some limit, with a small interval between checks to keep itself alive?

---

**P.S :**  I can't use Firebase Cloud Messaging as that's not the requirement of the client creating the app. The requirement is to create an independent Notification service.

---

Comment: Why do you want to implement this on device it self ideally app should listen to notification from remote server not local redis

Comment: The Redis server is remote, not local

Comment: Still connecting your mobile app to remote redis is not good; redis is used to cache in memory for quick retrieval but using it in mobile app kills its use case

Comment: Yes, but it can be used as a Messages Broker, which is what I'm using it for